# C# Compute dollar denomination

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Here is a code to find the total ways to get 87 with 4 different bills. I'm wondering how to change this to get the least amount of bills (4-twenties, 1-five, 2-ones) instead of every single way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int target = 87;
int[] dollarSizes = { 1, 5, 10, 20 };
int[] ways = new int[target+1];
ways[0] = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < dollarSizes.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = dollarSizes[i]; j <= target; j++) {
        ways[j] += ways[j - dollarSizes[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would to keep track of how many bills you had to use to reach $87 in an array. Then, you can simply look for the smallest number in that array and it will be your minimum number of bills required.

Comment: Homework? Seems like something my son would have as a question.

Comment: Also, note that there is a legal $2 bill.

Comment: @CadeRoux that would be in the requirements I'm sure ;) like ... the ones the professor gave out

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        int target = 87;
        int[] dollarSizes = { 100, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
        int[] counts = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        int remainder = target;
        int bill = 0;
        while (remainder > 0)
        {
            counts[bill] = remainder / dollarSizes[bill];
            remainder -= counts[bill] * dollarSizes[bill];
            bill++;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Really what you want to track is how quickly you can get to the target. So given 20,10,5,1 denominations, the code looks like this in psuedo

```
int initial = 87;             initial  twenties  tens   fives   ones
int twenties = initial / 20;    87        4
initial = initial % 20;          7        4    
int tens = initial / 10;         7        4       0
initial = initial % 10;          7        4       0
int fives = initial / 5;         7        4       0       1
initial = initial % 5;           2        4       0       1
int ones = initial;              2        4       0       1       2
```

As you can see, there's a lot of repeated logic, so that can be fed from a loop (where we *start* with the *largest value*).

Comment: I was going to use mod, but when I started testing, I totally forgot. Awesome solution :)

Comment: Seeing as though this looks homework-ish I'm glad you didn't give them the exact answer...

Comment: I would suggest renaming `initial` to perhaps `remaining`. It is confusing that initial is no longer the initial value in the end. `remaining` makes it much clearer.

Comment: @Reddog I figured giving him loops would be too much. All I really did was use the same logic a child should've known ;)

Comment: @Martinho ~ You are correct. Incidentally this is shitty code for solving this problem.

Comment: @drachenstein: I'm guessing `%` in your pseudo-language doesn't mean modulo, the way it does in C#?

Comment: @BenVoigt it should ... did I mess up my logic somewhere?

Comment: @drachenstein: Rather badly: `87 % 20` is `7`, not `4`.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh yeah, facepalm. I knew that there was no reason for me to use a -= in that logic, but this is what I get for not writing business logic before writing pseudocode :p ~ Also, at least two other people recognized the concept and overlooked the flaw as well :p

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int MakeChange(int amount)
{
    if (amount < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Amount should be greater than 0.");

    int[] availableBills = { 20, 10, 5, 1 };
    int[] availableBillCounts = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int iterator = 0;
    int reminder = amount;

    while (reminder > 0)
    {
        availableBillCounts[iterator] = reminder / availableBills[iterator];
        reminder = amount % availableBills[iterator];
        iterator++;
    }

    return availableBillCounts.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Count up using the highest bills first. If the new amount is too large, don't add that bill, and move on to the next dollar size:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = 87;
        var current = 0;
        var dollarSizes = new[] { 1, 5, 10, 20 }.OrderByDescending(x => x); // just make sure they're descending.
        var bestWay = new List<int>();

        foreach (var dollarSize in dollarSizes)
        {
            while (current + dollarSize <= target)
            {
                current += dollarSize;
                bestWay.Add(dollarSize);
            }

            if (current == target)
                break;
        }

        foreach (var dollar in bestWay)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}, ", dollar);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```