# How to find all possible values of 100 dollar bill

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

```
banknotes provided = 10 Dollar, 50 Dollar, 100 Dollar
```

Expected Result for 100 dollar bill with above bank notes.
I want to show the denomination exactly like below

```
5 x 10 + 1x 50
2 x 50 
1 x 100 
10 x 10
```

As you can see all the banknotes denomination total to 100 above

Comment: This is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Is there a programming problem in your code that makes it incorrect or failing otherwise?

Comment: Its not working as of now . I wanted to show my work so you have an idea what i am doing as well.

Comment: Then please explain what's wrong ([edit] your question). Now it looks like a request to review code.

Comment: When there are more than one possible combination of numbers of notes, do you want just a single combination, or all possible combinations? For example, if the total were 150, do you want `2 x 50 + 5 x 10` only, or also `1 x 50 + 10 x 10`?

Comment: Please don't remove the code. That turns the question into something that looks like a "please write my code" request which is generally not appreciated on Stack Overflow and tends to attract downvotes. You should explain (and show) that you tried and why it was insufficient.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602374/109941

Comment: @JimG. That question and answer has nothing to do with this question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the problem in two:

1. Solve the exchange problem of `total` given `notes` (in descending order), starting from nominal at `index`.
2. Provide the solution in required format

Code:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Solutions(int total, int[] notes, int index) {
  int value = notes[index];

  if (index == notes.Length - 1) {
    if (total % value == 0)
      yield return new int[] { total / value };
  }
  else 
    for (int i = total / value; i >= 0; --i) 
      foreach (int[] rest in Solutions(total - value * i, notes, index + 1))
        yield return rest.Prepend(i).ToArray();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Solve(int total, int[] notes) {
  var items = notes.OrderByDescending(item => item).ToArray();

  foreach (int[] solution in Solutions(total, items, 0)) 
    yield return string.Join(" + ", solution
      .Zip(items, (count, note) => (count, note))
      .Where(pair => pair.count > 0)
      .Select(pair => $"{pair.count} x {pair.note}"));
}
```

Demo:

```
int total = 170;
int[] notes = new int[] {10, 50, 100};

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Solve(total, notes)));
```

Output:

```
1 x 100 + 1 x 50 + 2 x 10
1 x 100 + 7 x 10
3 x 50 + 2 x 10
2 x 50 + 7 x 10
1 x 50 + 12 x 10
17 x 10
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xtBuAS)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
var notes = new[] { 10, 50, 100 };
var total = 100;
```

You can use a LINQ Extension Method to create all possible combinations of notes and filter them to just combinations that could be  used to create the total. I sort the notes in the combination descending so that the final answer will be output in descending order:

```
var possibleCombos = notes.Where(n => n <= total)
                          .AllCombinations()
                          .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(n => n).ToList())
                          .Where(c => c.Sum() <= total && c.Aggregate(total-c.Sum(), (r, n) => r % n) == 0)
                          .OrderBy(c => c.Last());
```

While it doesn't apply to the example, the `Aggregate` expression ensures that impossible combinations aren't selected, such as trying to make `{ 50, 20 }` yield `100`.

For each possible combination, you can start with the total and then take away one of each note to ensure at least one of each note is in the answer. It then computes the number of additional notes needed for each denomination, starting with the largest. For each combination it outputs the number of each note in the format requested:

```
foreach (var combo in possibleCombos) {
    var numberOfNotes = Enumerable.Repeat(1, combo.Count).ToList(); // one of each denomination
    var remainder = total - combo.Sum(); // start by taking away one of each denomination
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < combo.Count; ++j1) {
        numberOfNotes[j1] += remainder / combo[j1]; // take away all possible of each denomination
        remainder = remainder % combo[j1];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" + ", numberOfNotes.Select((numberOfNote, j1) => $"{numberOfNote} x {combo[j1]}")));
}
```

The extension method is defined as:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> start) {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> HelperCombinations(IEnumerable<T> items) {
            if (items.IsEmpty())
                yield return items;
            else {
                var head = items.First();
                var tail = items.Skip(1);
                foreach (var sequence in HelperCombinations(tail)) {
                    yield return sequence; // Without first
                    yield return sequence.Prepend(head);
                }
            }
        }

        return HelperCombinations(start).Skip(1); // don't return the empty set
    }
}
```

NOTE: This only produces one possible solution for each combination of bills, the one that uses the maximum possible number of the largest denomination.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (way less compact and cool than Dmitry's) solution, that uses recursion as you said. Basically I create a tree for each possible sum of the available banknotes that starts with the given amount at the root. For example, for your given amount of 100, and the given notes 10, 50, 100, I create the following pictured trees (and more), where the leaf values represent the individual banknotes that make up the total amount.

[image]

The leaf values then get transformed to your output, and possible duplicates (since different trees can be created from the same bank notes) are not printed out.

---

The following input:

```csharp
int[] availableBanknotes = { 10, 50, 100 }; 
int amount = 100;

SolveRecursive(amount, availableBanknotes);
```

prints out:

```csharp
10 x 10
1 x 50 + 5 x 10
2 x 50
1 x 100
```

---

The following input:

```csharp
int[] availableBanknotes = { 10, 50, 100 };
int amount = 170;

SolveRecursive(amount, availableBanknotes);
```

prints out:

```csharp
17 x 10
1 x 50 + 12 x 10
2 x 50 + 7 x 10
1 x 100 + 7 x 10
3 x 50 + 2 x 10
1 x 100 + 1 x 50 + 2 x 10
```

---

Here is the code:

```csharp
private static List<string> Solutions = new List<string>();

private static void SolveRecursive(int amount, int[] availableBanknotes)
{
    List<int> denomination = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < availableBanknotes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (amount >= availableBanknotes[i])
        {
            ProvidedBanknotes(amount, availableBanknotes[i], availableBanknotes, new List<int>(denomination));
        }
    }
    Solutions = new List<string>();
}

private static void ProvidedBanknotes(int amount, int currentBankNote, int[] availableBanknotes, List<int> denomination)
{
    amount = amount - currentBankNote;
    denomination.Add(currentBankNote);

    if (amount == 0)
    {
        PrintSolution(denomination, availableBanknotes);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < availableBanknotes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(amount >= availableBanknotes[i])
        {
            ProvidedBanknotes(amount, availableBanknotes[i], availableBanknotes, new List<int>(denomination));
        }
    }
}

private static void PrintSolution(List<int> denomination, int[] availableBanknotes)
{
    string solution = "";
    for(int i = availableBanknotes.Length - 1;  i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int currentVal = availableBanknotes[i];
        int count = denomination.Where(temp => temp.Equals(currentVal))
            .Select(temp => temp)
            .Count();
        if (count != 0)
        {
            if(solution.Equals(""))
            {
                solution = $"{count} x {currentVal}";
            }
            else
            {
                solution = solution + $" + {count} x {currentVal}";
            }
        }
    }
    if(!Solutions.Contains(solution))
    {
        Solutions.Add(solution);
        Console.WriteLine(solution);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
public IEnumerable<List<int>> GetDenominations(List<int> denominations, int value) =>
    GetDenominations(new List<int>(), denominations, value);

private IEnumerable<List<int>> GetDenominations(List<int> bills, List<int> denominations, int value)
{
    int sum = bills.Sum();
    if (sum == value)
    {
        yield return bills;
    }
    else if (sum < value && denominations.Any())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < denominations.Count; i++)
        {
            List<int> denominations2 = denominations.Skip(i).ToList();
            List<int> bills2 = bills.Append(denominations2.First()).ToList();
            foreach (var result in GetDenominations(bills2, denominations2, value))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That produces all valid combinations of the denominations that add up the `value` passed.

I get the results like this:

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> results = GetDenominations(new List<int>() { 10, 50, 100 }, 170);
```

And formatting is just a little LINQ work:

```
string output =
    String
        .Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            results
                .Reverse()
                .Select(xs =>
                    String
                        .Join(
                            " + ",
                            xs
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                                .GroupBy(x => x)
                                .Select(x => $"{x.Count()} x {x.Key}"))));
```

That gives me:

```
1 x 100 + 1 x 50 + 2 x 10
3 x 50 + 2 x 10
1 x 100 + 7 x 10
2 x 50 + 7 x 10
1 x 50 + 12 x 10
17 x 10
```